# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 508

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting an error like `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 508`. I am confused by this, please help me, where I am I going wrong.

This is the `getpack` function:

```
getpacks(): Packs[] {
this.dataSource.getpacks().subscribe(packList => this.packList = packList);
  console.log('"repository"');
  console.log(this.packList);
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.packList))) ;
return this.packList;
```

This is the http calling function:

```
 getpacks(): Observable<Packs[]> {
    console.log('rest');
       return this.http.request(new Request({
         method: RequestMethod.Post,
         url: '/Dev/getPack',
         body: {
          'ownerID': 1001,
          'outputMsgFlag' : '',
          'outputMSg' : ''
        },
         headers: this.headers,
       })).map(response => response.json());
     }
```

This is the function getting values and assigning to packList:

```
   get packList(): Packs[] {

        return this.repository.getpacks();

      }
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "packList": [
        {
            "pack_id": 1,
            "pack_name": "Bangalore Janapriyaa",
            "pack_type": "base pack",
            "base_price": 124,
            "cgst_amount": 11.16,
            "sgst_amount": 11.16,
            "total_tax": 22.32,
            "total_amount": 146.32,
            "active": "Y",
            "created_on": "2016-09-20 14:49:00.0",
            "created_by": "Abhishek",
            "owner_id": 1001,
            "modified_on": "2016-09-27 08:29:00.0",
            "modified_by": "Dynabox",
            "disabled_on": "",
            "comments": "My name is Scott Chow\r"
        },
        {
            "pack_id": 2,
            "pack_name": "Vijaynagar Janapriya",
            "pack_type": "base pack",
            "base_price": 128,
            "cgst_amount": 11.52,
            "sgst_amount": 11.52,
            "total_tax": 23.04,
            "total_amount": 151.04,
            "active": "Y",
            "created_on": "2017-01-05 04:18:00.0",
            "created_by": "Abhishek",
            "owner_id": 1001,
            "modified_on": "2017-06-14 11:51:00.0",
            "modified_by": "Zoombox",
            "disabled_on": "",
            "comments": "and I am going to be your guide on this journey to building a successful blog. I have been building blogs and websites since 2002.\r"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting an error like this. Please check it and tell me any solution please:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 508
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.json (http.es5.js:797)
    at MapSubscriber.project (rest.datasource.ts:95)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1020
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1080
next @ core.es5.js:4503
schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3635
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:238
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.es5.js:3621
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:3912
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:392
```

Comment: This means that your JSON content is invalid at position 508. We have no way of telling what's wrong without seeing the JSON content.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where position 508 is, but I guess it is your response that is invalid.
You should return `JSON.stringify(this.packList)`. Not just `this.packlist`

You could **hit F12** in your browser to check your response in the **network tab**.